# Estimating the area between two ecdfs

Tags: r, cumulative-distribution-function

I wish to calculate the area between two ecdfs in R (see below):

```
x<- 1
y <- c(0.329, 0.635, 0.558, 0.397, 0.719, 0.657, 0.356, 0.685, 0.618)
plot(ecdf(x), do.points = TRUE, verticals=T, xlim=c(0,1))
lines(ecdf(y), lty=3, verticals=T)
```

A hint in the right direction will be much appreciated.

The plot would look like this:

[image: ecdf]

I wish to calculate the area between the dotted line (ecdf(x)) and the solid line  (ecdf(y)).

Comment: (1) To what end?  (2) did you really mean for your plot to look like that? Perhaps you can include an image of what you think plot produced by that code was supposed to look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Offhand, I'd suggest estimating this area using using `mean(x) - mean(y)`

The reason is because for a positive random variable $X$ with cdf $F(x)$, it can be shown that $E(X) = \int_0^\infty [1 - F(x)]dx$. This is sometimes called the "old actuaries' trick"; to prove it, use integration by parts.

Thus, $\int\{F_Y(t) - F_X(t)\}dt = \int\{[1-F_X(t)] - [1-F_Y(t)]\}dt = \mu_X-\mu_Y$

I am curious, though, why you would ever want to look at the ECDF of a sample with only one observation.

Comment: Thanks Russ. I wish to compare the goodness-of-fit of a model tested over different data as estimated using a performance metric (ecdf(y)) with the ideal value for the metric, which is 1 (ecdf(x)). Since the ideal value does not change, there is only one observation. Helpful ?

Comment: Well, then, you are not comparing two empirical cdfs; you're comparing one ecdf with a known cdf. There's a difference! Also, if you're saying F(x) = 1, that's not what you have: with one observation at x=1, the cdf is F(x) = 0 for x<=1, and 1 if x>1.

Comment: BTW, looking at your graph you added to your question, note that you can view the area you want as the sum of areas of rectangles each of height $\frac1n$ and widths $1-y_1, 1-y_2, \ldots, 1-y_n$. Thus, the area is exactly equal to $1-\bar y$, just as I answered originally.

Comment: For future readers who are interested in a proof of the "old actuaries' trick", see ["Proof of expected survival time formula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function#Properties).

Comment: @mhdadk LOL I'm long since retired, and pretty sure I haven't thought about the OAT in the almost 8 years since I posted this answer.

Comment: @RussLenth I actually had a follow-up question: is the signed area between the two CDFs being equal to the difference in means no longer true if both $X$ and $Y$ have negative support? Must both $X$ and $Y$ have non-negative support?

Comment: I think you are OK as long as both X and Y have all their support above a *finite* negative value and have continuously differentiable cdfs, because then you could use the OAT on the distributions of X + c and Y + c where c is chosen so they both have positive support. The expectations are both increased by the same amount c so the difference of means is unchanged.

Comment: Although this is a nice trick, it only works if $F_Y(x)\geq F_X(x)$ for all $x$. See my answer below for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @russ-lenth does not work if the two ECDFs intersect as in the following example:

[image: overlapping ECDFs]

because in this case you can no longer pull the absolute value out of the integral:

$$\int \Big|F_x(x) - F_y(x)\Big|\, dx \neq \left|\int F_x(x)\,dx - \int F_y(x)\,dx\right|$$

Nevertheless, the result is very easy to compute because the difference between both functions is a step function and the area between them is thus simply the sum of rectangles, i.e. the scalar product (aka "dot product") of cell heights and widths. Here is a simple implementation in R:

```
# example data
x <- c(1,4,5)
y <- c(3,3,6,6)
Fx <- ecdf(x)
Fy <- ecdf(y)

# compute areay between ECDFs
xy <- sort(unique(c(x,y)))
heights <- abs(Fx(xy) - Fy(xy))[-length(xy)]
widths <- xy[-1] - xy[-length(xy)]
area <- heights %*% widths
```

Obviously, `abs(mean(x) - mean(y))` yields a different value.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think in most applications, AUC is used as a performance measure, and the area between curves is then the difference between AUCs, which is a *signed* area. In fact, one of the comments refers to signed area.

Comment: @russ-lenth In one comment, the original poster mentioned goodness-of-fit, which is measured by some distance metric on the CDFs, e.g. Kolmogorov (maximum), L1 (which is computed by my code above), or Cramer-von Mieses (L2).

Comment: Good point. Kind of like a two-sided alternative.